# How to specify the fully qualified class name of parquet while reading a trained spark mllib model to the code - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am new to Spark so please bare with the beginners way of explaining a problem.

I have a trained Spark MLlib model that I am trying to load into my pyspark code.

```py
model = RandomForestClassificationModel().load('file:///home/nuser/trained_model')
```

But when the code runs on the cluster I get the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for parquet (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.parquet.ParquetDataSourceV2, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat), please specify the fully qualified class name.;
```

I know that there is a way to specify the format for cases where there are multiple csv formats in the code by specifying the format (`ex:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.csv.CSVDataSourceV2`) like shown below:

```py
df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.csv.CSVDataSourceV2") .option("header", "false").schema(schema_format).load(file loc).
```

I want to know if there is a similar way to specify the fully qualified parquet class name while loading the model to fix this issue, if not how do I remove one of the sources to get rid of the error.

- pyspark version : 3.0.1